# encrypting a string via binary manipulation

Tags: python, string, binary

I'm running into a problem involving encrypting strings.  What I'm doing is converting each letter into numbers using `ord()` function and then converting it into binary codes.  Which I then invert or xor the numbers so that for the letter '`A`' which have binary code of '`0100 0001`' will become '`1011 1110`' when converted back to decimal value will be `190`, which I will chr() back into a letter.  I've noticed that certain letters don't convert into any symbols that can be seen at all.  When I tried to convert decimal value of `157` to `ASCII` character.  I got '`\x9d`' instead of a ASCII value. According to the Extended ASCII Codes, it should have given me a symbol that I can read with print function and also print it to a file.  Is there any way to make Python print it into a readable symbol so that I can print it?  Right now I'm unable to make it work due to the inability of the program to print it into symbols that I can read and reverse the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python defaults to showing the representation of strings unless you explicitly print them. `\x9d` is the `repr` (representation) of the character, if you print it you will see something else depending on which encoding and font your terminal uses

```
>>> chr(157)
'\x9d'
>>> print repr(chr(157)) # equivalent to the above
'\x9d'
>>> print chr(157)
� # this appears as a question mark in a diamond shaped box on my system
```

This doesn't stop you from writing the data to a file though.

**EDIT**

If by "Extended ASCII" you are referring to this character set http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437, you should be able to use

```
>>> print chr(157).decode('CP437')
¥
```

This returns a unicode string suitable for printing (if your terminal supports that).

**EDIT 2**

It's a little different in Python 3.x as `ord` returns a unicode str. Instead you want a `bytes` str (which is equivalent to a Python2.x str):

```
>>> bytes([157]) # this is equivalent to ord(157) in Python 2.x
b'\x9d'
>>> bytes([157]).decode('cp437') # decode this to a unicode str with the desired encoding
'¥'
>>> print(bytes([157]).decode('cp437')) # now it's suitable for printing
¥
```

Make sure when you write the data to a file that you write the raw `bytes` str, not the unicode (printable) str:

```
>>> data = bytes([154, 155, 156, 157])
>>> print (data.decode('cp437')) # use decode for printing
Ü¢£¥
>>> with open('output.dat', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(data) # but not for writing to a file
...
4
>>> with open('output.dat', 'rb') as f:
...     data = f.read()
...     print(data)
...     print(data.decode('cp437'))
...
b'\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d'
Ü¢£¥
```

Comment: I've just tried it in the python IDLE Shell and it said "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", I then tried using print(___) (___ being chr(157).decode('CP437'), it didn't work either.  It said "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' and I tried doing it without print.  Same problem.  str doesn't have decode.  I'm using the Python IDLE 3.3.2, I know it's different from the 2.x python.  Any suggestions?  I used both dir and help, there's no decode nor encode in chr().

Comment: @user3444888 I've updated the answer with code for Python 3.x

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!  Is there a way to reverse it?  When I tried using ord() it gave 165, but the initial value was 157.

Comment: @user3444888 No worries, if this answered your question please mark it as the accepted solution. When converting back using `ord`, make sure you are converting the raw byte string data, not the unicode version. `ord(bytes([157]))` works fine, so you might need to use `ord(data.encode('cp437'))` if your data is in unicode form.

Comment: Okay, how do I mark it as accepted solution?  I just tried using encode but it doesn't work.  I put the bytes([157]).decode('cp437') into a variable Y, but when I tried reversing it, it didn't give the original value.  It gave 165 instead of 157.  ord(data.encode('cp437')) should I use the Y in place of data?  I tried that but it said str can't be interpreted as int.

Comment: Click the little tick mark (✓) near the voting arrows at the top of my answer. `y = bytes([157]).decode('cp437'); print(ord(y.encode('cp437')))` gives the correct result here. Are you sure you didn't use `chr` instead of `ord`?

Comment: Yeah I used ord.  Ah now it worked.  I didn't use the ord inside print the first time, but now it's working.  Thanks!!!